# Vue displaying only last array item

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I've a Vue component that I iterate over an array as follows:

```
@if($categories!=null)
    @foreach($categories as $category)
       <accordian></accordian>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

The `$categories` array has 3 objects.

```
 <script id="accordian-body" type="x-template">
        <h4 v-on:click="toggleOpen()">{{$category->name}}</h4>
 </script>
```

When I run this, I'm always get the last array object in the accordian. The count is correct (3 in this case), but the data is always the same. Why is it so?

> Item3 
> Item3 
> Item3

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing blade and vue in a way that doesn't work.  Your template comes after the for loop, so the value of `$category` when you get to the template is just the last element from the array.

You should go all-in with Vue like so:

**JS:**

```
var Accordion = Vue.extend({
  props:['category'],
  template:'#accordian-body'
});
```

**Component**

```
...
data:function(){
  return {
    categories: {!! json_encode($categories) !!}
  }
},
components:{
  accordion:Accordion
}
...
```

**Accordion Template**

```
<script id="accordian-body" type="x-template">
    <h4 v-on:click="toggleOpen()">@{{category.name}}</h4>
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<accordian v-for="category in categories" :category="category"></accordian>
```

Comment: I've added this to the js file: `Vue.component('accordian', {
    template: '#accordian-body',
    data: function(){
        return {
            open: false,
            categories: {!! json_encode($categories) !!}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggleOpen: function(){
            this.open = !this.open;
        }
    }
});` but it shows an error in the json encode area.

Comment: try wrapping with Json.parse() like Json.parse({!! json_encode($categories) !!})